# Is it better to ask a new question or place a bounty on an old one?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, policy, bounty

Let’s say that Reuven posts a question, and Shimon posts an answer to that question. I don’t like Shimon’s answer for reason XYZ. Is it better for me to post a bounty on Reuven’s question, asking for other answers and explaining why I don’t like Shimon’s answer, or should I just ask my own question detailing all of that information? Would it be considered a duplicate in the latter case?

In the event that a user isn’t able to make a bounty (i.e. not enough reputation), are the rules different?

Comment: See the FAQ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess that’s part of the question, if the same procedure applies and it’s better to make a bounty rather than to make a new question.

Answer (score 5):

If what you really want is that same question answered, but not with *that* answer, then yes, a new question post would likely be a duplicate of the first one

Here are some things you can do to try to get more, better answers. Only the first three have any reputation-score restriction associated with them.

- Add a bounty.
- Comment on the answer you don't like, explaining what you see as its shortcomings, and asking for the author or others to fix them. (This doesn't necessarily apply if the answer is just fundamentally wrong.)
- Call attention to the question in Mi Yodeya chat.
- Share the question post with your social network.
- Find an expert on the topic and ask him/her personally for help.
- Research the question yourself and write an answer.

Comment: But asking on that answer itself - “I don’t like XYZ because ABC. Has anyone addressed this issue?” - would not be a duplicate, correct?

Comment: @DonielF It really depends on the actual content involved. But if the question you really want answered is the one that was already posted, trying to get it answered via a follow-up post is likely to get messy, one way or the other.